# Store a threaded view in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tree

I am parsing a threaded forum (tree with parent_id joins) and am trying to store the single postings in ElasticSearch while keeping the hierarchy. However I am not quite sure what the best way would be.

**parent/child model**: The difficulty here is, that the root elements don't have parents + I am not sure whether or not I can point `_parent` to its own type.

Also a bonus question on this one. When inserting, do I need to pass the parent as query param or can I add it in the data-object as well?

**nested model**: I cannot tell in advance how deep the tree might get and I don't really to put *useless* objects in the mapping

I feel that this would be not such an uncommon task to do, so any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend taking your approach for this purpose.

Using both **parent/child** and **nested** you would have to pre-define the maximum depth of your tree, and articulate that with some nasty mapping.  (While enumerating each level's field in your search queries.)

With **parent/child** you'd actually be creating additional indices for each level, which adds unnecessary resource overhead.

Is Elasticsearch your primary datasource?  If not, consider simply indexing forum posts as a flat collection of documents with enough information present to be able to reconstruct the thread from your primary.  E.g.:

**POST**

- Thread ID
- Author ID *(perhaps not needed for search?)*
- Post ID
- Parent ID *(perhaps not needed for search?)*
- Post Date
- Post Title
- Post Body

Then Elasticsearch is reduced to the role of text search / highlighting engine, and will happily give you back snippets and Post IDs/Thread IDs needed to reconstruct the thread from the database.

If Elasticsearch **is** your primary store, then hopefully [you've read this thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-shouldnt-I-use-Elasticsearch-as-my-primary-datastore) already.  There is a commercial Elasticsearch plugin created by [Siren Solutions](http://siren.solutions/) which enables Elasticsearch to manage truly schemaless, nested data like yours.

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer.. As it turned out I did try your advice of flatten the data (adding a sort and depth field), which does work, however - well - I thought I am doing it all wrong..  
I stumbled upon your 1st link a few times, but never read it to be true ;) .. and will look in the 2nd tomorrow ..

Comment: I think my question here is what happens if the post title or body changes? Update all the documents?

Comment: I think maybe `Post Body` should really be just `Body` for the post or for any response.  In forums, responses don't usually have different titles, so maybe it's not necessary to duplicate the title in the responses.  But yes, if an element is duplicated, and is later changed, then you need to figure out how to update it wherever referenced.